# Image thumbnails size with JSSor

Tags: jquery, jssor

I came across a similar question but not sure how best to implement the answer posted. I'm using the jssor plugin and each of my thumbnails vary in size. I need to have them conform to the sizes they are listed as but in the way this is set up now each one is set to be 72px x 72px. I've tried setting the width and height to 100% but not sure where exactly that should go as its not really working. Do I add this into this code or what am I missing? Thanks for any help

```
  <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; background: black;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 72px; HEIGHT: 72px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
                <div class="o" style="position:absolute;top:1px;left:1px;width:72px;height:72px;overflow:hidden;">
                    <ThumbnailTemplate class="b" style="width:72px;height:72px; border: none;position:absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;"></ThumbnailTemplate>
                    <div class="i"></div>
                    <ThumbnailTemplate class="f" style="width:72px;height:72px;border: none;position:absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;"></ThumbnailTemplate>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the actual code. I found the info but not sure how it works in here. I'm using a php script but am finding it somewhat complex to figure this out. Thanks:
`foreach ($result as $row)
    {
    echo "<div>
          <p><small><span style=\"color:white\">To explore images click on smaller image below to start.</span></small></p>
                <a href=\"http://mirrorofrace.org/TemplateZoom.php?photo_id={$row['photo_id']}\" target=\"_blank\"><img u=\"image\" src=\"http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row['full_size']}\" alt=\"\" ></a>
                 <img u=\"thumb\" src=\"http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row['thumbnail']}\"  alt=\"\" style=\"border: 0\">
                 <br><span style=\"color:white\">Click Image to Zoom&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"../gallery/profile.php?photo_id={$row['photo_id']}\">Info Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['figure_1']}</span>
                 </div>";
    }
?>
        </div>`

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: not sure where to post the code.I don't see a place

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
<img u="thumb" src="../img/landscape/thumb-01.jpg" />
```

with

```
<div u="thumb">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(../img/landscape/thumb-01.jpg); background-size: contain;"></div>
</div>
```

and you can change property value of 'backgorund-size' to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see <img u= "thumb" etc in the code for the gallery. Where do I find that?

Comment: Just posted the actual code above. Sorry for the other posting, I think this is what is needed to be changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<img u=\"thumb\" src=\"http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row['thumbnail']}\"  alt=\"\" style=\"border: 0\">
```

Comment: sorry, still not sure what i'm replacing here

Comment: this is code wrote by a developer, please ask the developer to apply new code for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<div u=\"thumb\">
    <div style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row['thumbnail']}); background-size: contain;\"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps but for some reason each thumbnail is now doubling or making two images side by side of the same image. The images are larger which is what I wanted to have without distortion but they are not correct. http://mirrorofrace.org/container1.php

Comment: I think one problem is that many of these images are vertical which might be a cause of the issue. The thumbnails are generally something like 50 x 70 give or take.

Comment: One more thought. Can this work if the width is called as $row["thumbnail_width"] and height as the $row["thumbnail_height"] I'm not sure how to use this with jssor scripting but it worked in another php script and seems to function there. I've tried writing this in the php here but no luck making it work. I know I'm doing something wrong but can't seem to figure it out. Appreciate any other help. The older site seems to be able to manage this: http://mirrorofrace.org/container.php but I want to use the jssor slider which is much better than the old iframe we were using. thanks

Answer (score 0):

please add background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; as follows,

```
<div u=\"thumb\">
    <div style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(http://mirrorofrace.org/{$row['thumbnail']}); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;\"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, that works very well. One more question please, how can I decrease the space between the images in the thumbnail? thank you for helping, I really appreciate it.

Comment: you can adjust value of '$SpacingX'